# Stop Mouse pointer sticking - snapping when going from Macbook to External Screen above

Tags: display, mouse

In the picture the Red line is where my mouse sticks.
it has a snap to grid like feel.
it does not stick at the other external monitor boundary just the top of the mac screen.
and only when 2 displays are touching top and side boundaries.

This is my setup

[image]

This is where it sticks (RED) - unfortunately you cannot fully see it because I covered it with red but if you look closely the top menu grey line on the mac is curved, this ends up being the key to the problem.

[image]

This is where it doesn't stick

[image]

It also does not stick if the macbook is at the top (but this is not an option)

Answer (score 1):

In this picture the Grey bar has sharp corners.

I just had to play around with it until it looked like this.

now I actually have trouble replicating the issue. the screens snap together more easily now.

In the picture to see the curve and circle it.

[image]

Here is the original picture you can see the start of the curve and hence the screens had not perfectly snapped together, but I was still able to transition across the boundary somehow, even though there was a small gap.

[image]

So this is not a fix to the problem more of a work around to prevent the problem.

SO JUST PLAY AROUND WITH IT UNTIL IT COMES RIGHT!